# Unable to create iqn at targetcli?

Tags: centos7, iscsi

I want to make a san on my virtual machines, I have already configured a server1 as Server target with theses steps:

```
- create lvm on server1
- install targetcli
- create blocks 
- create iqn using: create iqn.2017-26.com.example:target1
```

When I tried to create iqn, I got this message:

```
WWN not valid as: iqn, naa, eui
```

Any help!

Answer (score 0):

The IQN format takes the form iqn.**yyyy-mm**.naming-authority:unique name, where:

- **yyyy-mm is the year and month when the naming authority was established.**
- naming-authority is usually reverse syntax of the Internet domain name of the naming authority. For example, the iscsi.vmware.com naming authority could have the iSCSI qualified name form of iqn.1998-01.com.vmware.iscsi. The name indicates that the vmware.com domain name was registered in January of 1998, and iscsi is a subdomain, maintained by vmware.com.
- unique name is any name you want to use, for example, the name of your host. The naming authority must make sure that any names assigned following the colon are unique, such as:

  - iqn.1998-01.com.vmware.iscsi:name1
  - iqn.1998-01.com.vmware.iscsi:name2
  - iqn.1998-01.com.vmware.iscsi:name999

However **2017-26** is not a valid date 26 month do not exist.

Comment: Are you quoting someone here?  Can you format this to reflect that if so?